# Not getting proper output from RandomAccessFile java

Tags: java, system.out, randomaccessfile

So here is the code that I ran.

```
import java.io.*;
public class SETBQ1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RandomAccessFile item = new RandomAccessFile("item.dat", "rw");
    String s;
    while ((s = item.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    item.close();
  }
}
```

By the way, the contents of item.dat are

```
1 pencil 100 10
2 pen 200 5
3 eraser 5 1000
4 book 500 12
```

However, the output I am getting is

```
PS F:\tymalik\Malik\SEM 1\JAVA\ASS5> java SETBQ1
1 pencil 100 10
2 pen 200 5
3 eraser 5 1000
4 book 500 12
null
```

I would like to know why that last value prints null instead of a value?
and what would be the solution to process the string variable outside of the while loop? I would appreciate any help on this one.

Comment: Hi @malik bagwala, do you want to use line that you used for reading right?

Answer (score 1):

The last statement

```
System.out.println(s);
```

displays `null` since it is outside the scope of the `while` loop. You could assign another variable within the loop instead

```
String lastLine = null;
while ((s = item.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
    lastLine = s;
}
System.out.println(lastLine);
```

Comment: But I want to process it further outside the white loop. So what should I do?

Comment: @malikbagwala What exactly do you "want to process further"? At this point the variable `s` always holds the value `null` because that's the condition for leaving the loop.

Comment: I wanted to search for the costliest item among those.

Comment: That is quite different from your original question